# Environment Variables returning None when running Python script from Cron

Tags: python, cron, environment-variables

I have set my environment variables in /etc/profile and ~/profile. When I run an echo $EVNAME it returns correctly but running it as a Cron job returns None.

I'm running it on Raspberry Pi 4 and script using Python3.

Any help with this one?

Answer (score 0):

The proper path for the profile file is `/etc/profile`. If you're intending to set it to a specific user, it's `~/.bashrc`.

See here: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-in-linux/#persistent-environment-variables

Comment: I've set my EV in /etc/profile, ~/profile, .bash_profile and now ~/.bachrc. Always the same result from Cron, None. Why does't Cron see these EV?

Comment: Are you able to get the environment with `echo $MY_VAR` in the console? did you ran the `source` command to "reload the environment variables? Is the cronjob calling directly the python script or via an shell script? @Benzine

Comment: Based on the associated answer it now works. I added . etc/profile; before running my script, it now works. Thanks for your help.